# Pentaho "Get file from FTP" times out

Tags: ftp, timeout, pentaho

Pentaho's get file from FTP step fails randomly. Sometimes it properly downloads the file, sometimes it doesn't returning error:

```
Error getting files from FTP : Read timed out
```

The timeout is set to 100 seconds and the read actually fails after less than one seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what the [Get a file from FTP documentation](https://pentaho-community.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EAI/pages/371558464/Get+a+file+with+FTP) says about the timeout, **it is not in seconds, but in milliseconds**.

Change it to any reasonable value like 60000 (1  minute in ms) and your import will work.

Comment: Just to share the new URL https://pentaho-community.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EAI/pages/371558467/Get+a+file+with+SFTP

Comment: and this one with the reference of timeout https://pentaho-community.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EAI/pages/371558464/Get+a+file+with+FTP